# Implicit DLL linking works for keyboard hook but not WH_SHELL hook

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, keyboard, hook

I've successfully created a WH_KEYBOARD_LL hook inside a program. I've put the callback in a DLL, which I link to the main EXE implicitly. Everything works great (the app helps me with PC automation-type tasks).

I now want to add a WH_SHELL hook, but am having less luck.

EXE project (Visual C++ 2022):

```
// pcautomation.h
#pragma once
#define WINVER 0x0500
#include <Windows.h>
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

// pcautomation.cpp
#include "<path>\pcautomation.h"
#include "<path>\keyboardCallback.h"
#include "<path>\shellCallback.h"
using namespace std;

HHOOK hhKybd;
HHOOK hhShell;
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int cmdShow) {
  // ... <register application window, etc> ...

  // THIS WORKS JUST FINE
  hhKybd = SetWindowsHookExW(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, (HOOKPROC) KeyboardHookProc, NULL, 0);
  if (NULL == hhKybd) return 0;

  // THIS DOES NOT WORK. hhShell IS SET TO NULL, INDICATING FAILURE
  hhShell = SetWindowsHookExW(WH_SHELL, (HOOKPROC) WHShellProc, NULL, 0);
  if (NULL == hhShell) return 0;

  // ... <message loop, etc> ...
  return 0;
}
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
  // ...
  return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

DLL project:

```
// pcautomation-dll.h
#pragma once
#ifdef NAX_PCA_DLL_EXPORTS
#define NAX_PCA_DLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define NAX_PCA_DLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
#define WINVER 0x0500
#include <Windows.h>

// pcautomation-dll.cpp
#include "<path>\pcautomation-dll.h"
#include "<path>\keyboardCallback.h"
#include "<path>\shellCallback.h"

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved) {
  switch (ul_reason_for_call) {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
      break;
  }
  return TRUE;
}

// keyboardCallback.h
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>
LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardHookProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

// keyboardCallback.cpp
#include "<path>\keyboardCallback.h"
using namespace std;
LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardHookProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
  ...
  CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

// shellCallback.h
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>
LRESULT CALLBACK WHShellProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

// shellCallback.cpp
#include "<path>\shellCallback.h"
using namespace std;
LRESULT CALLBACK WHShellProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
  if (nCode < 0) return(CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam));
  if (nCode == HSHELL_WINDOWCREATED) {
    ...
  }
  return 0;
}

// source.def
LIBRARY pcautomation-dll
EXPORTS
  KeyboardHookProc
  WHShellProc
```

VS 2022 is set up with the configs I understand necessary for implicit DLL linking:

- source.def set as the module definition file for the DLL project linker
- lib output from the DLL project added as a linker dependency in the EXE project
- VS solution build order set to DLL first, EXE second

As you can see in the code, I'm setting `dwThreadId` of `SetWindowsHookExW` for both hooks to 0 because I do not want to limit what threads respond to the hooks, they should work globally.

Regarding the `hmod` param, I'm aware that the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexw) say it "must be set to NULL if the dwThreadId parameter specifies a thread created by the current process and if the hook procedure is within the code associated with the current process," and yet I do so despite that `dwThreadId` isn't specifying such a thread. And this seems to work for the keyboard hook. Is the WH_SHELL hook different? Does it *require* an explicit DLL handle?

I'm concerned I'll have to reconfigure the entire setup to use explicit DLL linking just to get that handle (and there's a ton more code and use of the DLL than what I show here).

Comment: `hmod == 0` and must be not for `WH_SHELL`

Comment: @RbMm thank you, could you possibly rephrase (I don't understand)?

Comment: `SetWindowsHookExW(WH_SHELL, (HOOKPROC) WHShellProc,  GetModuleHandleW(L"pcautomation-dll"), 0)`

Comment: `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` is *global only* and [called in the context of the thread that installed it. The call is made by sending a message to the thread that installed the hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/lowlevelkeyboardproc). While `WH_SHELL` is *thread or global* although `WH_SHELL` should also [be called on the thread that installed the hook rather than the thread processing the hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexw#remarks).

Comment: @RbMm that solved it thank you! I ended up putting `HMODULE dllMod = GetModuleHandleW(L"pcautomation-dll")` in its own line so I could call `FARPROC newWindowProc = GetProcAddress(dllMod, "WHShellProc")`, passing the result of that too to `SetWindowsHookExW`. (Once I got the correct module handle, putting `WHShellProc` directly in `SetWindowsHookExW` would crash explorer?). Glad I got your suggestion, feel free to add as an answer if you'd like.

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT that explanation makes sense and clears up a lot, thank you for this!

Answer (score 0):

> yet I do so despite that dwThreadId isn't specifying such a thread.
> And this seems to work for the keyboard hook. Is the WH_SHELL hook
> different? Does it require an explicit DLL handle?

According to [SetWindowsHookEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexw), you need to set `hmod` to the DLL containing the hook procedure pointed to by the `lpfn` parameter just as others hooks.

The question should be, Is the `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` hook different?

The explanation could be `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` is *global only* and [called in the context of the thread that installed it. The call is made by sending a message to the thread that installed the hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/lowlevelkeyboardproc).

Comment: Would another way to say it be that, because ["the global hooks are a shared resource"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa), even if the callback is in a DLL, that DLL need not be injected into the processing thread?

Comment: It, "the global hooks are a shared resource", applies on all global hooks. But *be aware that the WH_MOUSE, WH_KEYBOARD, WH_JOURNAL\*, WH_SHELL, and low-level hooks can be called on the thread that installed the hook rather than the thread processing the hook*.

Comment: Thanks. So I think I get now that `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` doesn't need the DLL handle because it's called in the context of the installing thread. But I guess that opens a new question for me (which I may post separately): if `WH_SHELL` as well "can be called on the thread that installed the hook," then in what instances would that happen? Because I can't seem to get away with not giving it the DLL handle?

Comment: It seems global "global only" and global "thread or global" hooks must operate through different mechanisms. E.g. with "global only" hooks called via messaging like you said--always within the installing process--and the absence of the DLL handle posing no problem because anyway it wouldn't be used? Whereas global "thread or global" hooks become global via DLL injection--into every potentially calling process--and _don't_ use messaging? (Where of course these too may end up called on the installing thread--warranting the note in the docs--but only incidentally / due to the specific event?)

Comment: I suppose only *Global only* hooks are special. You can try other *Global only* hooks for example `WH_MOUSE_LL` or `WH_SYSMSGFILTER` to see if it's necessary to specify a handle to the DLL containing the hook procedure.